# Why does Samsung camera app not work without Bluetooth permission?

Tags: bluetooth, camera, samsung-galaxy

Since the latest update (I think some time in December 2022), the built-in camera app on my Samsung Galaxy S21 asks for "Nearby devices" permission, and refuses to run if I don't grant it. By "Nearby devices" it means "Bluetooth". I don't know why it calls the permission
"Nearby devices": all other references to Bluetooth call it "Bluetooth",
and you can also access a nearby device using Wi-Fi or even NFC if the device
is close enough.

It doesn't actually need Bluetooth to take photographs, or even to record movies,
but you *might* have a Bluetooth microphone (I don't) and you *might* want to use
it to get better sound quality when recording a movie.

Of course the Android best practice advice at
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview
is not to ask for runtime permissions unless and until you need them,
but Samsung aren't doing that.

I don't want the camera app to announce my presence by probing the Bluetooth headset of
anyone who happens to be near me, and they might regard such an action as intrusive.
So I don't want to give the camera app its nearby devices permission, but it won't
run at all without it.

So how do I get the camera app to run without accessing Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

I found some workarounds for this. If your device supports it, you can download Expert Raw from the Galaxy Store. This will take still photos without requiring "Nearby devices" permission. However it doesn't seem to be able to do selfies because there seems to be no way to switch cameras, and it can't do movies or many of the extra tricks that the full camera app can do.

Another option is to run the camera app with Bluetooth disabled. Then it can have its "Nearby devices" permission, but it can't use it. The problem with this is that if you use Bluetooth at other times you have to remember to disable it and enable it.

So I wrote a tiny app which disables Bluetooth, runs the camera app, and restores the previous enabled or disabled state of Bluetooth when the camera app exits. I put this on my home screen instead of the camera app: it has the same icon. You have to remember to exit properly from the camera app using the Back button: the Home or Recents buttons leave my app and the camera app sitting on the task's back stack, so my app doesn't get to run and restore the Bluetooth state.

The app is available [on github here](https://github.com/rparkins999/SafeCamera) in case anyone else wants to use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to not use the delivered camera app and download an alternate app: Cymera or Open Camera... both work pretty well. Both are free. There are others, some free and some with a cost.